# How do I do this loop integral?

Tags: integration

I'm having some trouble doing a loop integral. It is the loop integral that gives neutrinos their mass in the famous Zee model (http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(80)90349-4).

The integral is

$$
\int \frac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4} \frac{1}{k^2-m_h^2} \frac{1}{k^2-m_\phi^2} \frac{1}{k^2}.
$$

The integral is convergent so there is no need for any regularisation scheme. I have tried to do the integral using the Feynman parameter:

$$
\frac{1}{ABC} = \int_0^1 dx \ dy \ dz \ \delta(x+y+z-1)\frac{2}{[xA+yB+zC]^3}
$$

and then the master equation for loop diagrams:

$$
  \int \dfrac{d^4 k}{(2\pi)^4} \dfrac{1}{\left( k^2 - \Delta + i\epsilon  \right)^n} = \dfrac{(-1)^n i}{16\pi^2} \dfrac{\Gamma(n-2)}{\Gamma(n)}\left(\dfrac{1}{\Delta}\right)^{n-2}.
$$

Unfortunately none of the answers I'm getting look like those given in the paper. The integral should come out to something like:

$$
m_h^2 \log(m_h^2/m_\phi^2)
$$

for $m_h > m_\phi$.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you end up with?

Comment: Something like: $\int dx \int dy \frac{1}{xm_h^2+ym_\phi^2}$ ?

Comment: The final answer you quote doesn't have the same dimensions as the original integral, are you missing a factor? Also it might help if you could give more detail on what you've done.

Comment: Indeed, sorry I should have included more detail. Vertex factors and the like sitting at the front of the integral contribute another 3 dimensions of mass, which gives the term total mass dimension 5. It seems logical at this point to suppose that there should be a negative in front of the 2 on the $m_h$ term exponent. I always feel uncomfortable saying that a published paper has a typo, but it wouldn't be a first. This gives the correct dimension and is actually part of the answer I got. The integral does end up looking like what you show, hft. Thanks for all your responses!

Comment: The vote to migrate to the maths SE goes against the meta post on math and physics. Whilst it's not become official policy, this should stay as it is motivated by physics. Whether it can be closed as homework-like is another matter.

Answer (score 3):

I think i got it: You have $$I=\int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{1}{k^2-m^2_h}\frac{1}{k^2-m^2_\phi}\frac{1}{k^2}$$ in order to calculate this integral in an easy way we make a wick rotation to put ourselves in 4-D euclidean space i.e. $k_0\rightarrow ik_0$ this means that $d^4k=i d^4k$ and $k^2=k_0^2-\vec{k}^2=-k_0^2-\vec{k}^2$ so $k_0^2+\vec{k}^2=-k^2$ if you substitute in the integral you will have: $$-i\int \frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{1}{k^2+m^2_h}\frac{1}{k^2+m^2_\phi}\frac{1}{k^2}$$ ok now we use 4-D spherical coordinates$d^4k=d\Omega k^3dk$:  $$-\frac{2\pi^2}{\Gamma(2)}i\int_0^\Lambda\frac{dk}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{k}{k^2+m^2_h}\frac{1}{k^2+m^2_\phi}$$ now let's split the integral: $$\frac{k}{k^2+m^2_h}\frac{1}{k^2+m^2_\phi}=\frac{A}{k^2+m^2_h}+\frac{B}{k^2+m^2_\phi}$$ you will find that $$A=\frac{1}{m^2_\phi-m^2_h}\\B=-A=\frac{1}{m^2_h-m^2_\phi}$$ so you have $$-\frac{2A\pi^2}{\Gamma(2)(2\pi)^4}i\int_0^\Lambda dk k [\frac{1}{k^2+m^2_h}-\frac{1}{k^2+m^2_\phi}]$$ which is now trivial: $$\int_0^\Lambda dk \frac{k}{k^2+m^2_i} =\frac{1}{2}log\left(\frac{\Lambda}{m_i^2}\right)$$ so $$I=-\frac{2A\pi^2}{\Gamma(2)(2\pi)^4}i\cdot \frac{1}{2}log\left(\frac{m^2_\phi}{m^2_h}\right)=\frac{i}{16\pi^2}\frac{1}{m^2_\phi-m^2_h}log\left(\frac{m^2_h}{m^2_\phi}\right)$$
i hope that helped!

EDIT:

Well the simplest justification that comes to my mind is that $k_0=ik_E$ is invertible and as regular as a linear transformation can be so every operation that was allowed before is allowed after the trnasformation. Ok so consider these two facts: the pole is not in the origin as far as $k_0$ is concerned but it's in $k_0^2=\vec{k}^2$ whichy gets mapped to the immaginary axis that means you have no ambiguity in the choice of an integration path (for $k_0$) since the poles don't overlap with the real axis after the rotation, second: if you choose to integrate in spherical coordinates then you have to take into account the presence of measure which gives a $k^3$ contribution that removes the singularity in $k_0=\vec{k}^2$.

A more rigorous approach would require you to do the Wick rotation at the path integral level, on $Z[J/..]$ which is a prefectly legitimate operation on the action integral $x_0=i x_E$ so when you derive the green functions from the generating functional they already are Wick rotated and so are their poles without any ambiguity. 
I hope that clears your doubt a bit let me know if it doesn't unfortunatley these days i have very few time spare.

Comment: Thanks so much, this makes a lot of sense. Just one question: the integrand has a pole at the origin of the complex plane, are you still allowed to do the Wick rotation in this situation?

Comment: i edited the answer since the comment was getting too long